# How to place footnotes at the end of the page?

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

There are 15 pages of parallel text and a few familiar footnotes.

The problem is that all of these footnotes placed on 16th page (even if I defined footnote at first page). How can I place footnotes at the end of the page?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{pages}
   \begin{Leftside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \footnoteA{some footnote} \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \endnumbering
   \end{Leftside}
   \begin{Rightside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \endnumbering
   \end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your MWE, for which thank you, only to get "undefined control sequence `\beginnumering`". Having corrected that to `\beginnumbering` the footnote appeared on page 2 of the document (page 1 was empty) and not on the last page. Please provide an MWE that actually shows your problem.

Comment: @PeterWilson, thanks. MWE was updated. The footnote is on 6th page, but footnote definition is on second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have lost track of the `re...` packages but your problem seems to be associated somehow with line numbering. The following MWE (a merge of yours and my original attempt) does put the footnote on the same page that it is specified.

```
% reledparprob.tex  SE 594556

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

%\usepackage{reledmac} PW changed this for
\usepackage[series={A,B,C},noend,noeledsec]{reledmac} % this on OP's original MWE
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
\linenumincrement{1000}
%\numberlinefalse   % PW commented this out
\begin{pages}
   \begin{Leftside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \footnoteA{some footnote} \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \endnumbering
   \end{Leftside}
   \begin{Rightside}
      \beginnumbering
    \linenumincrement{1000}
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart ............ \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \pstart tons of text \pend
      \endnumbering
   \end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps Maieul Rouquette (`maieul AT maieul DOT net`), the current maintainer, maybe able to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just pasted at the top of the document `\firstlinenum{10000} \firstlinenumR{10000}`